# Insert blank row into excel

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2011

I've been using this Excel program as a data base with this particular information for 5 years, inserting rows for alphabetical arranging on a regular basis. Now all of a sudden, can't do it. This error message:

> To prevent possible loss of data, Mic. Excel cannot shift non blank cells off the worksheet. (not doing that) Try to delete or clear the cells to the right and below your data. Then select cell A! and save your workbook to reset the last cell used. (why so complicated all of a sudden?) Or, you can move the data to a new location and try again.

Comment: How many rows are there in your workbook? Maybe it has reached the maximum number so excel can't increase anymore

Comment: Excel thinks your data is taking up more space than it actually is. Since you have been inserting rows for quite some time, you finally reached a point where Excel believes that you have data in the last few rows of the worksheet. To find out where Excel thinks your data range ends, press the End key and then the Home key. I bet you'll be surprised. It's easy to fix by deleting the empty rows below your actual data and the empty columns to the right. May be weird - but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the "empty" rows in the Excel sheet:

1. Put your cursor in the row below what you consider the last row with data.
2. shift+ctrl+down to select that row and all the rows below it.
3. right click > Delete > Entire row
4. save the file (this is important)

Now you should be able to insert blank rows again.